# Generate data from sample CSV file

Tags: text-processing, date, csv

I have sample CSV data file with 1M records with 1 date (14/03/2017 00:11:17) only. I need to generate 6 month data from this sample CSV file. Bash script taking 20 Minutes to generate 1 day data.

DATA SAMPLE

- *'12/01/2017 03:22:17,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464'*

EXPECTED RESULT

- '01/01/2017 03:22:17,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464'
- '02/01/2017 03:22:17,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464'

  to
- '30/01/2017 03:22:17,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464'

Comment: what does mean *to generate 6 month data* in your case? should it be ordered? should it be saved into separate files?

Comment: I have only 1 Day data with date of "12/01/2017 03:22:17". I want to generate data from "01/01/2017 03:22:17" to "01/07/2017 03:22:17" from CSV file which has 1M rows. I tried with BASH + SED was too slow to generate data. Hence required to help of perl or python script

Comment: @R C, so you have 1M rows of same *1 Day data* ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Yes

Comment: So, for each 1M rows of your existing data, you need to make about 180 copies of it (with incrementing dates)?

Comment: @glennjackman, Yes

Comment: maybe use http://filldb.info and then import to a sql server and then export...

Answer (score 1):

```
cat 6months.pl
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Text::CSV;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use autodie     qw/ open close /;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, quote_space => 0}); 
my $dateparser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => "%d/%m/%Y %T", time_zone => "local");

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        my $datestr = shift @$row;
        my $date = $dateparser->parse_datetime($datestr)->truncate(to => month);
        my $end = $date->clone->add(months => 6);
        while ($date <= $end) {
            $csv->say(STDOUT, [$dateparser->format_datetime($date), @$row]);
            $date = $date->add(days => 1);
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Running it:

```
perl 6months.pl data.csv
```

```
01/01/2017 00:00:00,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464
02/01/2017 00:00:00,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464
...
30/06/2017 00:00:00,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464
01/07/2017 00:00:00,sampledata,1234,sample,123455,67546464
```

---

Just noticed this resets the time to midnight. If you want to keep the time, do this instead:

```
    my $date = $dateparser->parse_datetime($datestr)->set(day => 1);
    #                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```